# Is there a MySQL feature like SQL Server's TIMESTAMP column?

Tags: mysql

My preliminary research says "no".

I have a database app in SQL Server that uses the SQL Server timestamp column for tracking changes.... that is, I can go through the table and know that if I see a timestamp > than some reference timestamp, that the row has been added or updated.

I'm looking for a type like that in MySQL.  It doesn't seem to exist.  So, will I have to replicate this functionality using either triggers (good) or application logic (bad)?

Note that just using MySQL's TIMESTAMP isn't really a great solution, as it's not always unique, and not monotonically increasing over time.

EDIT ---  here's the scenario I've been using these for, for years...

I have a table in a OLTP system which is the current state of the inventory.  I have a front end GUI that's displaying different views of the inventory.  I'd like to occasionally go and ask the DB "which rows are new/changed".  With SQL Server's TIMESTAMP/ROWVERSION, I could do that easily.  If I use an actual date type, I would always run into problems where I either got an update more than once (not a huge disaster), or occasionally missed an update (a disaster).

Comment: Timestamp/rowversion is not guaranteed to be unique. it can be duplicated if you try to do insert multiple rows using select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why this doesn't work for your scenario.  Is `TIMESTAMP` guaranteed to be unique in MS SQL Server?

Aha -- I see in SQL Server timestamp is a synonym for [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) which is sort of like MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` except it generates a new monotonically increasing value on `UPDATE` as well as on `INSERT`.

No, MySQL doesn't have anything like this.  Nor does MySQL support a `SEQUENCE` object like Oracle or PostgreSQL or IBM DB2.  A sequence would allow you to generate a new value from a trigger, for instance.

---

I read your updated info in your question, so I understand the problem you are trying to solve.

What I have seen as an alternative solution is to add another attribute in the table you're processing, call it `is_processed` or something.  Enter a NULL when you insert a new row.  When you get around to processing it, change the value in that column to 1.  Then you'll always know which rows you have yet to process -- they'll be the rows where `is_processed IS NULL`.

---

Re your comment:  Okay, I see the problem.  Each user needs their own view of which rows are new/changed.

Another hack I've seen used in MySQL to simulate a sequence object is a table that contains an auto-increment primary key and nothing else.  You can generate new unique monotonically increasing values by inserting into this table, and then roll back the insert.

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (id SERIAL) ENGINE=InnoDB; -- Must be InnoDB

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES (); -- Yes this is a legal statement.
ROLLBACK;

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

You can't start and rollback transactions within a MySQL trigger, so you'll have to generate the new values in your application code.

Or else you could switch to PostgreSQL, and get real support for sequences.

Comment: "What I have seen as an alternative solution is to add another attribute in the table you're processing, call it is_processed or something."

That won't work.... assuming there is one table, but many GUI users.

Comment: You can emulate a sequence in mysql like here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,143867,194058#msg-194058 . And you could use that in an BEFORE UPDATE/BEFORE INSERT trigger to update a custom version column you'd have to add to your table. (And yes, it's very very painful)

Comment: Yes, that solution is pretty bad for concurrency, since MyISAM does a table lock during an update.  MySQL seems to have no good solution for this case.

Comment: Do you need MyISAM tables ? InnoDB would be more suitable for that

Comment: @nos: The solution in that forum link relies on MyISAM because it's not subject to transaction isolation.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to add a Guid column ( (char(36) ) to  your MySql table and in the insert and update triggers assign a new Guid value each time.

This will serve the same function as the timestamp as it will guarantee a unique value with each insert/update.

Answer (score -1):

If the monotonicity problem is due to daylight saving time,
you can set the time zone to UTC when checking TIMESTAMP columns:

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Alternatively, you could fill DATETIME columns with UTC_TIMESTAMP using triggers.

Unfortunately, neither idea enforces uniqueness, nor will they prevent race conditions with transactions.

Comment: I would guess there's also a problem with uniqueness if you update multiple rows in a single `UPDATE` statement.  The timestamp of an update is identical for all rows updated by the same statement.