# Is it possible to get last update time of the row in sql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to get last updated time and date of the row using MYSQL server.

Comment: No you have to include a field that will include a timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is-there-a-mysql-feature-like-sql-servers-timestamp-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364051/is-there-a-mysql-feature-like-sql-servers-timestamp-column)

Comment: also check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html for the same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well there is no inbuild feature exists with MySQL. Though you can get the same effect by adding a timestamp column:

```
ALTER TABLE NAMEYOURTABLE
   ADD COLUMN last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

using above to create timestamp with name last_update column will make it pretty much automatically managed and updated. Now you can select from NAMEYOURTABLE the last updated row based on the timestamp.